# Error accessing the NamedResolutionCollection

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm using the Exchange API with C#. I am trying to access the NamedResolutionCollection and I am getting the following error: 
"This property was requested, but it wasn't returned by the server." Is this a permissions issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(this depends on the property but generally)If a particular property isn't set on the Item then EWS won't return it as null and that error is how the EWS Managed API has been written to surface it. In EWS Managed API you can use TryGetProperty to check if a property has been returned.

```
Object SubjectValue = null;
if (Email.TryGetProperty(ItemSchema.Subject, out SubjectValue))
{

}
```

The Subject is a extreme case and not generally needed but I have seen that same error on that prop when scanning through every item in a Mailbox.

Comment: So, when you mean set, do you mean that it has no value? So if it's null, it won't return null, it just throws this error?

Comment: What happens in the response the property is not returned (which is what the error is telling you) and if you look a the Item with a Mapi editor like OutlookSpy of MFCMapi you won't see that property on the Item. If the property was set and has a blank value or null value (which is also possible but generally this is caused by 3rd party apps not setting the props correct) it will still be returned in EWS and MAPI. It comes down to the way they decided to handle this type of situation in the EWS Managed API

Comment: I see. So for some reason, I suppose how my company has outlook set up so that I won't get this property back. It's not that it's null or blank, it's just that they don't have the value set.